# Python Pandas , Date '9999dec31'd

Tags: python, pandas, sas

I am doing something very simple but it seems that it does not work. I am importing a SAS table into pandas's dataframe. for the date column. I have NA which is actually using '9999dec31'd to represent it, which is 2936547 in numeric value. Python Pandas.read_sas() cant work with this value because it is too big. Any workaround?

Thank you,

Comment: What exactly happens when you run `read_sas`? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same error, but with SQL server data, not SAS.  I believe Python Pandas may be trying to store this as a pandas datetime, which stores its values in nanoseconds.  9999DEC31 has far too many nanoseconds, as you might expect, for it to handle.  You could try reading it in as an integer of days since the SAS epoch, or a string, and use the datetime module (datetime.date) to store it.  Or read in the year, month, day separately and recombine using class datetime.date(year, month, day).  Whatever gives you the least amount of grief.  I can confirm that datetime.date CAN handle 9999DEC31.

Because datetime.date is not a native Pandas class, your column would be stored by Pandas as dtype "object".  But never fear, if you've done it right, every single element would be a datetime.date.

Please note: If you need to work with those datetime.dates in Pandas, you would have to use the methods and objects provided in datetime, which differ from the pandas.datetime.

I hope that helps.  Let me know if you need more info.